# How to replace a numeric character with empty character in C#?

Tags: c#, string, replace, numeric

I have string like

```
  1 69 / EMP1094467 EMP1094467 :  2 69 / ScreenLysP
```

here the numeric characters should be replace with empty characters, Llike:

```
/ EMP1094467
```

I tried like this

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[\d-]", string.Empty);
```

which produced the following result:

```
/ EMP
```

Please suggest a better solution.

Comment: you mean replace numbers, not numeric characters (i.e. there are numeric chars in "EMP1094467")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using word boundaries:

```
var input = "1 69 / EMP1094467 EMP1094467 :  2 69 / ScreenLysP ";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\b[\d]+\b", string.Empty);
```

Comment: ...and in case you don't understand the regex - `\b` stands for word boundary, `[\d]+` - one or more of any digit

Answer (score 0):

`string.Substring` seems fitting here:

```
var str = "1 69 / EMP1094467";
var result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf("/")); // "/ EMP1094467"
```